# Getting the current logged in username in a Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

So I have a Controller, which requires the username. What's the difference between these two?

```
public function myFunc(Request $request) {
    $username = $request->user()->username;
}

public function myFunc() {
    $username = Auth::user()->username;
}
```

Is one better or more secure compared to the other? Which one should I be using over the other?

Comment: If you're going to downvote, explain why.

Comment: no difference, there is also another one: auth()->username works too. The reason is that a lot of people hated on Facades in laravel. So for a lot of Facades there is a helper method too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference.
the first  one uses the auth facade and the other one uses the Request class , eventually they give the same results with no real performance impact,

I prefer the first one in my controllers, i only use the Auth facade in my views.

Comment: What's the logic behind why you prefer the first one for Controllers and the second for Views? Is there any difference security wise? The keyword here is security. I've seen people hack Laravel sites but they wouldn't tell me how they did it.

Comment: nope , a facade provides a static-like interface to access a method, that's the only difference!
I prefer that way for no reason at all! ( i put the { in  a line on it's own too! it's personal preference)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the reply. In that case I'm thinking I'll probably use the Auth::user() method since there's less typing involved.